# SaveAsTextFile not writing

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

I'm working in Python, using Hadoop, and PySpark. I have an RDD that I output at the end of my code (I have verified that it outputs correctly), that I am trying to save as a text file using the `.saveAsTextFile()` method.
The code runs to completion and generates a `_success` file but the rest of the directory is empty.

```
outputFile='hdfs:///data/withCoalesce'
combinedTable= all_transactions_reduced.join(credit_payments_reduced)
combinedTableMapped= combinedTable.map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1][0])+x[1][1]))
combinedTableMapped.coalesce(1, shuffle=True).saveAsTextFile(outputFile)
```

When I go into Hadoop FS and look at the files in the directory they're all empty. Does anyone know why this might be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `collect()` to retrieve and print the data before the `saveAsTextFile()` call. This should tell you what exactly is in the RDD. The easiest explanation would be if the RDD is empty.

Why do you do `coalesce(1)`? This prevents you from working with large amounts of data. I recommend not doing it. But, if the data is small, and you really want to have a single file, you could just use `collect()` and write the file from the driver instead of using `saveAsTextFile()`.